# Why is it that in numpy certain methods (e.g. np.dot) can be called with dot notation, while others (e.g. np.insert) cannot?

Tags: python, numpy, oop, methods

Just starting to learn about OOP and the distinction between methods and functions. Having some difficulty with a few very basic concepts.  My understanding is that methods are generally callable in two equivalent ways.

```
object.method(parameters)
```

or

```
class.method(object, parameters)
```

**Question** Why is it some numpy methods are callable with these two notations while other methods appear to work with only one?  For example, if A and B are both numpy arrays of the same length, I can call numpy.dot as either

```
np.dot(a,b)
```

or equivalently

```
a.dot(b)
```

However for some methods like numpy.roll or numpy.insert (where the method is operating on one object as opposed to two)this is not the case.

```
np.insert(a,[0],[1])
```

works fine while

```
a.insert([0],[1])
```

returns the following Attribute error

```
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'insert'
```

Is this because np.dot is a method that is specific to the ndarray subclass whereas np.insert may be a method for all numpy objects, which makes it in effect only callable as a function?

any insight would be helpful thanks!

Comment: Ideally all relevant `numpy` functions would be implemented as `ndarray` methods as well, but that would make for a lot of double work, both in implementation and when updating.  I'd imagine they only implement functions as object methods when 1) it's a very commonly used operation or (especially) 2) when having access to the underlying data structure makes a method more efficient than a function (as it is with `ndarray.dot()`)

Comment: also, having everything be a method can make for some long and dense code that can be hard to parse (see `pandas` where method chaining is endemic)

Comment: `np.dot` is a function.  `a.dot` is a method.  Same for `np.sum` and `a.sum`  The function form makes its arguments into arrays and then calls the method.  `np.insert` is a function writen in python without a compiled method equivalent.  `np.sin` is a `ufunc` function, without any method equivalent.

Comment: this is very helpful.  Thank you guys so much for the insight! @hpaulj When you say the function form "makes its argument into arrays", does this mean that the function form will have greater overhead since it has to convert to the object to arrays first? ... or am i totally misunderstanding you?

Comment: There's a bit of added overhead, but if the argument is already an array it's minimal, the equivalent of a call to `np.asarray(obj)`.  Usually you can use either depending on what makes your code most readable.  Sometimes you have to use one or the other.  If `a` is a list, you have to use `np.dot(a,b)`, but if `a` is a `scipy.sparse` matrix, use the `a.dot(...)` form (or the `a@b` operator form).

Comment: In the big picture, `numpy` has a large number of compiled `ndarray` methods.  Many of those also have function counterparts, that facilitate use with non-array arguments, and provide more documentation.  But there are also a lot of functions that don't have equivalent methods, some pure python, others in the special `ufunc` category.  `operators` also get translated to method calls.  All categories are documented.

Comment: I see thanks, your examples always help alot @hpaulj, so the method is tailored to an object of a specific class (e.g. ndarray)...whereas the function is generally written to accommodate multiple classes of objects(e.g. lists, ndarray, ints).  Whether a method is worthwhile making is measured in the convenience of calling via method as compared to the cost of compiling the method and the maintenance issues Daniel F notes above?

Comment: `method` and `function` are integral to Python's object/class design.  In some languages everything has to be a method of some class or other.  Python allows both.  You can write functions.  You can also define classes with their own methods.  While we can discern patterns in the choices `numpy` developers made, we shouldn't try too hard to figure out the `whys` or define rigorous rules.

Answer (score 1):

I might be wrong but you might be interested in having a look at: [https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/60cd9d717524e5a003bee9e4270b9c6b8144a7af/numpy/**init**.pyi#L1358](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/60cd9d717524e5a003bee9e4270b9c6b8144a7af/numpy/__init__.pyi#L1358)

where you can see that ndarray implements a `dot` method in which it seems to pass itself as the first parameter and then take a second "arraylike" input. Hence the `obj.dot(other_obj)`.

Comment: Thanks so much for taking the time to look this up and point that out!...yes and I suppose also in line with the comments above, insert and roll are absent from the list i.e. they have not been compiled as methods and so cannot be called as such.